# C character array printing numbers insted of the assigned charaters

Tags: c, arrays, maze

I am working on an assignment to solve a maze created from a 2d character array. To test the program I made a simple 4x4 maze. But the maze, when printed to the screen is comprised of numbers. I am very confused at how this even happens. Any help would be appreciated.

The assignment is this:

```
char *maze[4][4];
for (int i=0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    maze[0][i] = "#";
    maze[3][i] = "#";
    maze[1][i] = ".";
}
maze[2][0] = "#";
maze[2][3] = "#";
maze[2][1] = ".";
maze[2][2] = ".";
```

and printing is here:

```
for(int i =0; i < 4; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
        printf("%c",maze[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I expected it to print this:

```
####
....
#..#
####
```

But instead it prints:

```
0000
2222
0220
0000
```

Comment: Look up the meaning of `"%c"` in the `printf` documentation.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your question! Please read the short introductory [tour]. It mentions the [Help]; for example, help on formatting can be found on [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thank you so much to everyone. This helped my and the maze is printing correctly now. Once again Thank you so much

Comment: `char *maze[4][4]` is not a 2D character array, but a 2D array of **pointers to `char`**!

Comment: Why did you declare a bidimensional array of chars as a bidimensional array of pointers to chars.  Change `char *maze[4][4];` by `char maze[4][4];`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
maze[0][i] = "#";
```

should be

```
maze[0][i] = '#';
```

and `char *maze[4][4];` should be `char maze[4][4];`

`"#"` is a string literal, use `'#'` to have a character constant.

If you really want to use string literals of one character you have to use the `%s` conversion specification instead of `%c` in your original program.

Comment: `maze` is an array of `char*`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I did in the edit in the same time as your comment apparently

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in this line

```
printf("%c",maze[i][j]);
```

you are not using characters, but char pointers (aka strings) so this should go like:

```
printf("%s",maze[i][j]);
```

Or you can also use characters instead as described in other answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a type mis-match in the `printf` call. You're printing `maze[i][j]`, which is a `char *` (string), as a character (`%c`). I suggest turning on compiler warnings to catch these kinds of errors; gcc found the issue when I tried to compile your code.

The reason it prints a number instead of a character is because `printf` is interpreting the address of the string `maze[i][j]` as an ASCII code point and printing the corresponding character. For you compiler, the addresses of `"#"` and `"."` happen to result in the characters `0` and `2` being printed. It was different in my case; when I compiled your code, the program printed EOT and ACK.

The nicest solution would be to declare `maze` as an array of `char`s instead of strings.

```
char maze[4][4] = {
  { '#', '#', '#', '#' },
  { '.', '.', '.', '.' },
  { '#', '.', '.', '#' },
  { '#', '#', '#', '#' }
};
```